# Wanting to understand why this for loop will not work in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Was doing my assignment and tried doing a multi variable for loop where both value have the same increment. However, compiler is giving me an error saying im missing ) ; etc. I dont understand and hope someone can clarify for me. Thanks

```
for(int i = arr.length - 1; i >0; i--){
    String temp = "";
    for (int j =0 && int m = i; m < arr.length; j++, m ++){
        temp = temp + arr[m][j];
    }
    diagonalArray.add(temp);
}
```

Tried changing the `&&` to `,` but i get `error: <identifier> expected`
as my error.

Comment: The `ForInit` in the inner loop uses incorrect syntax: `int j =0, m = i`

Comment: My compiler spat out a total of 9 syntax-errors for that line and I'm pretty sure so did yours. Always start with the **first** syntax-error. The following errors will quite likely disappear or change. And have a look at the relevant section in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
int j =0 && int m = i
```

should be

```
int j = 0, m = i
```

Comment: Or just declare a single variable, say `m`, and use `m-i` in place of `j`.

Comment: Hey! Tried that but i get this in return. error: <identifier> expected